# Can I use the latest recommended Apache HttpCore 4.2.2 jar with the HttpClient 4.2.1 library?

Tags: android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

The latest version of the Apache HttpClient library is at 4.2.1 and includes the httpcore-4.2.1.jar core library.  However, a newer version of the core httpcore-4.2.2.jar is available.  The readme file for the new core recommends upgrading to the new core.

My question is, should I use the new httpcore-4.2.2.jar with the httpclient-4.2.1 or should I stick to the core version included in the HttpClient package?

I am using this package for Android devices.

Comment: theres a script that you can run in this project each time apache pushes a release. then you just rebuild your own httpclient.jar n.n.n and use that in android. http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/